# How to isolate bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, sass, less, bootstrap-5

I wanted to isolate bootstrap-5 styles to some spesific block, page or to 
can someone guide me for how to isolate bootstrap 5 for intire page or in some spesific .

Comment: Did you find out how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Add safeguard class to wrap your include:

```
.bs-5 {
    @import (inline) "@{cssPath}/bootstrap.min.css"
}
```

And then do this HTML structure:

```
<div class="bs-5">
    /* .. BS5 specific content .. */
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but did not work in my chrome extension. Can you please explain more? Here is the what I did:
`.bootstrap-iso {
@import (inline) "@{cssPath}/bootstrap.min.css"
}`
https://sharetext.me/og9wlihxkg

Comment: @John Did you provide correct path to bootstrap CSS? It warps any content inside that css file with `.bootstrap-iso` class.

Comment: Yes Actually in above comment I was not able to edit path but as both CSS files are in the same directory I just did this: `.bootstrap-iso { @import (inline) "bootstrap.min.css" }` that directory now has `bootstrap-iso.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`. Should I give the path from root directory or the relative path? I am not sure

Comment: @John It does not matter, as log as it works

Comment: The problem is it is not working

Comment: @John Try without `(inline)`

Answer (score 0):

Justinas' answer was the right way to do it for me.

Since I was using Sass and not Less, I had to remove the (inline) parameter. I also had to extend the `:root` pseudo class otherwise BS `:root` variables were nested in a `bs-5 :root` selector and were not accessible.

My setup with Vite (Sass):

```
#bs-5 {
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; 
}

:root * {
    @extend :root;
}
```

For more info on the `:root` nested variables issue: https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/1883

Then use it in html just like Justinas said:

```
<div class="bs-5">
    /* .. BS5 specific content .. */
</div>
```