# Modify CSS selectors in compiled CSS file after compilation with Vite / Sass

Tags: css, sass, vite

For a given project I had to import Bootstrap in an isolated CSS id to avoid conflicts with other versions (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75517666/14217548). I am working with Vite and Sass:

```scss
#bs-5 {
    @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; 
}
```

The issue is that the `:root` and `body` selectors of Bootstrap are now nested inside this `bs-5` id. In the complied CSS I ended up with `#bs-5 :root` and `#bs-5 body` selectors. I solved the issue with `:root` thanks to this code:

```scss
:root * {
    @extend :root;
}
```

However I cannot apply the same receipe to `body` since writing:

```scss
body * {
    @extend body;
}
```

Will produce this selector: `body #bs-5 *`, and will apply `body` styles to all elements, which I do not want.
I also tried:

```scss
body bs-5 {
    @extend body;
}
```

But since Sass `@extend` keeps the ancestors of the target I end up with the following selector: `body #bs-5 #bs-5`

I can of course copy/paste Bootstrap code for the `body` selector and put it in a `#bs-5 body` selector but this could break with future evolutions of Bootstrap if I forget to copy / paste again.

So my conclusion was that I cannot find the right solution with Sass and I should modify directly the compiled CSS file to replace the `#bs-5 body` selector by `body #bs-5`.
But I would like this modification to be automatized in my workflow (working with Vite) so my question is : How do I do that?

I see that Vite can use PostCSS so I was thinking of using this kind of plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-selector-replace
But I do not know if this is the best way to do it!